# Tivoli alert from java code

Tags: java, alerts, tivoli

Can anyone guide me how could I raise tivoli alerts from my java code.I searched for the API or documentation for tivoli netcool IBM product alert raising from java code but I couldn't find the exact match for my problem.

We are using netcool alert system to raise alert to the support system, If my application find any abnormal case in data we need to raise tivoli alert to investigate the data.

We have some alert methodolgy for system not available , server not in running mode.

Now am in need of populating this alert from java code. Other that sending mail to the group. How could I raise the alert in tivoli(some issue number for the issue ) so that we could track the issues later.

Please guide to find solution for this issue. I tried searching in stackoverflow but no one had raised such request, I saw same kind of question in          http://software.itags.org/ibm-websphere/256320/  but no had answered..

I'm exepecting help from some expert's answers from stackoverflow..

Thanks in advance..
Thanks!

Comment: I guess I'd check out the [Tivoli Information Center](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tivihelp/v8r1/index.jsp). Not always the easiest to search, but usually the most accurate. We were looking into something similar for Tivoli Service Request Manager and ran into email being the only way to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Netcool Omnibus is a glorified Sybase server when you get under the hood.  I don't do much with Java, but I have several alarms created from Perl DBI SQL inserts when SNMP traps are unavailable.  If you have a Sybase connector for Java write an insert statement to the table alerts.status to your Object Server's IP on port 4100.

Answer (score 1):

There is an SDK for sending events to Omnibus. You can download it as part of the standard product download.

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSNFET_9.2.0/com.ibm.netcool_OMNIbus.doc_7.4.0/omnibus/wip/eifsdk/concept/jaa63460.html

Note that you almost never send events directly to the Omnibus Objectserver itself. In order to control access, you send your events to a probe which handles the connections, locks, special handing rules and more with the Objectserver.

"hacking" the Objectserver by treating it as a regular sybase database can cause issues if don't know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I've just started writing Java.  I run the Systems Management software here at work.  I maintain and use both ITM 6.3  and Netcool 7.3.1.  If I understand you correctly you're looking for a way to send an alert (event instance) into Netcool.  If you have an EIF probe running, I can give you a class that will send an event to an EIF probe.  Just wrote and tested it last week.

Comment: This answer is incomplete. Once you have enough rep, please use comments to request further clarification from submitters.